# Why is my Illustrator drop shadow blocky?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: Drop Shadow]I'm sure this is an easy fix but I dropped some JPGs into Illustrator and when I try to add a shadow the shadow completely doesn't match the shape of the image. It's really wavy. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Because .png files allow transparency to be saved, in Photoshop I've removed the background of the image you posted and cropped the canvas size exactly to the image and saved the file as a “.png”.

In Illustrator I created a new document then went to menu item File/Place (choosing the link option) and placed that .png file into the illustrator document.

[image]

Next I went to menu item Effect/Document Raster Effects Settings.  I set the resolution to 300 PPI and transparent background

[image]

Next I went to menu item Effect/Stylize/Drop Shadow

[image]